# Validando formulario com jQuery e mandando para um controlador no codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Quero fazer uma validação com o jQuery antes de enviar os dados para o lado servidor, estou utilizando PHP com jQuery e na parte do form uso isso:

```
 < ? php echo form_open('empresa/inserir', 'id="form-empresa"'); ?>

     < inputs ...
     < button submit / >

  < / form >
```

Porém, sempre que dou o submit, ele manda direto para o controlador do codeigniter, ignorando a validação da página.

O que devo fazer pra que ele valide primeiro a página lado cliente com o jQuery, e se estiver tudo certo, chamar a função do codeigniter?

Comment: Que tipos de dados voce precisa validar?

Comment: Não seria mais fácil utilizar a library form_validation do codeigniter? Funciona muito bem. Se não souber utiliza-la dá um toque, eu posto um trecho de código para ajuda-lo.

Comment: Então eu preciso validar alguns campos input type text, tipo nome, email ... mas se eu usar o form_validation do codeigniter eu estarei validando pelo lado servidor, e eu queria validar pelo lado cliente, será que não tem algum metodo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar o prevent-default e faça sua validação client-side. Lembrando que muitos campos podem ser validados com HTML5, como o atributo required.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form-empresa').on('submit', function(e){
     var valido = false;

    // validações jquery aqui - atribua true para "valido" quando validar

    if(!valido) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu queria fazer, não havia pensado nesse preventDefault, e sobre a validação do HTML5 eu queria fazer algo mais estilizado com o jQuery por isso não utilizei ela! Obrigado!